# What are the ways to cover joint/mesh tape or sheetrock cracks due to settling?

Tags: drywall, painting

I notice cracks in paint or tape in the area where two sheetrocks join or where a tape is used at the corner. I assume these are mostly due to ground settlement and I am afraid they show up again if painted over. What are the alternate ways of covering these hairline cracks?

Comment: Far more important that putting a band aid on a cut artery is figuring out _why_ the house is settling and fixing _that_ first. If you don't then A) Yes, you'll have to fix the drywall again, and B) you might have to fix warped floors, broken ceiling joists, collapsed structures...

Comment: The age of the house will help.  A house less than 5 or 10 years these are common as the house settles and not usually a worry.  After ten years and they show up is not common and should be checked into.

Comment: @FreeMan We went through an expensive process of placing piers etc. But the problem has resurfaced.  And the piers themselves may initially cause those cracks. Soil moisture fluctuations can wreak havoc even if you have piers.

Comment: Normal moisture fluctuations should not cause many cracks if any.  Extreme changes can.  Replacement of piers would almost put the house back to the original 5 year settling stage.  Age of house or major support work is important to tell if common or needs checking.

Comment: @crip659  I am guessing that the drought conditions and the heat wave of portions of Texas will put many houses in trouble this year. On top of that mandatory water conservation will be an issue. Water your slabs!